# AgeRange not in Rekognition response

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-rekognition

[The docs](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/rekognition.html#Rekognition.Client.delete_faces) mention AgeRange in the response of detect_faces.

But, using the Python SDK (boto3), I cannot see it in the response.

Am I missing something? Is the feature in the docs but not yet in production (it is a new feature from feb 10th)?

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "..."
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "..."
os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] = AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] = AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

client = boto3.client('rekognition')
reko = client.detect_faces(
    Image={'S3Object': {'Bucket': '...',
              'Name': 'user_uploads/....JPEG',}},
    Attributes=['ALL']
)

res['FaceDetails'][0].keys()
# outputs 
# dict_keys(['Landmarks', 'Eyeglasses', 'Quality', 'Confidence',
# 'Mustache', 'Emotions', 'Smile', 'BoundingBox', 'Beard', 'Gender',
# 'Pose', 'EyesOpen', 'Sunglasses', 'MouthOpen'])
```

Comment: Are you using version 1.4.4?  You didn't mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to last version (`pip install -U boto3`). With `boto3>=1.4.4`, `AgeRange` is present is the response.

Thank you Michael for your comment.